# SAP IQ: Export to Client-Side

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

Is there a way to Export the tables from Sybase IQ 16 to flat files saved locally on my Client?

I can use Unload or Output to from ISQL to save it Server side but didn't find a solution for Client-Side file.

It would be fine also when it's not just usable in ISQL

Someone know a solution? :)

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible by using dbisql via Data->Export giving you are able to run it manually.

Comment: isnt it possible in a way with jdbc Connection and t-SQL?? and maybe with Batch files